# MySQL returns wrong results with the BETWEEN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am using the following query to get data from mysql database and I get wrong data. I want to show release_year from 1990 ~2000, but it's showing me everything.

```
SELECT title,release_year
FROM FILMS
WHERE 
    release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000
    AND budget > 1000000000
    AND language ='Spanish'
    OR language = 'French';
```

I tried to switch up the order of the query but it didn't seem working or I tried adding parentheses to `release_year between 1990 AND 2000` .

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have a *logical prescedence* problem.

These are your filter conditions:

```
release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000 
AND budget > 1000000000 
AND language ='Spanish'
OR language = 'French'
```

In logical operators, `OR` has lower prescedence than `AND`, so this is syntaxically equivalent to:

```
( 
    release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000 
    AND budget > 1000000000 
    AND language ='Spanish'
)
OR language = 'French'
```

Now you can see that this expression will allow any French movie, regardless of its release year and budget.

You probably want:

```
release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000 
AND budget > 1000000000 
AND ( language ='Spanish' OR language = 'French')
```

Which can be shortened as :

```
release_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000 
AND budget > 1000000000 
AND language IN ('Spanish', 'French')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good idea to force logical `and` and `or` precedence.

Try:

```
SELECT title,release_year 
FROM FILMS 
WHERE release_year between 1990 AND 2000 
AND budget > 1000000000 
AND (language ='Spanish' OR language = 'French')
;
```

or

```
SELECT title,release_year 
FROM FILMS 
WHERE release_year between 1990 AND 2000 
AND budget > 1000000000 
AND language IN ('Spanish', 'French')
;
```

*Recent versions of MySQL have made optimizations to `IN` that can make it perform better than the equivalent set of `OR` conditions.*

Note, I say *"always"* because even if `(a and b) or c` were your intended logic, adding the parenthesis makes your intention clear to the next person that looks at the query.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your comment about the optimisations to `IN`? I'd be interested to see what they've done (Not that they'd have to do much given how bad `OR` performance tends to be).

Comment: @Nick I don't really have a reference for it; that is just something I have seen other reliable contributors here state.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
SELECT title,release_year 
FROM FILMS WHERE release_year >= 1990 
AND release_year <= 2000 
AND budget > 1000000000 
AND (language ='Spanish' OR language = 'French');
```

If you have any question please comment below.